# is it possible to fix Unexpected child "generate" found under "flutter" in flutter stable channel

Tags: flutter

I am add international to my flutter app, when I follow [the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) and add config:

```
generate: true
```

shows this error:

```
Unexpected child "generate" found under "flutter".
Exception: Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at ./pubspec.yaml
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
```

I search from internet and tell me to switch to the master channel could fix this problem. but I want to stay stable channel, any other way to fix this? Is is possible to stay stable channel and avoid this problem? This is the flutter env info:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at /Users/dolphin/apps/flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (4 months ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dolphin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/dolphin/Applications/JetBrains Toolbox/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • 4FEAF225-103D-4237-96D7-026059D2BDB4 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-7
      (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
(base)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **Flutter version 1.20.4** but `generate` key was added in version 1.22. Update to the latest stable version.

[[flutter_tools] generate a synthetic flutter_gen package on pub get #61261](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61261)